# sql get date with year and month

Tags: sql, date

I have 2 variables in month and year, and I want to get the year value with these 2 variables. sample,
year=2018 and month=5, i want
'2018-05-01 00:00:000'
Thanks for help.

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select cast(cast(year as varchar(max))+'-'+cast(month as varchar(max))+'-01' as datetime)
```

Comment: no need for dashes and `varchar(max)`, we already know that year is 4 and month is two digits

Answer (score 0):

Try this .. you only have to format the date as `20180501` for SQL SERVER

```
declare @mm smallint = 5, @yy smallint = 2018
```

-- USING `CONCAT`

```
select cast(concat(cast(@yy as varchar(4)),right(concat('0',@mm),2),'01') as datetime)
```

--old concatenation method

```
select cast(cast(@yy as varchar(4))+right(concat('0',@mm),2)+'01' as datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

If SQL Server 2012 or higher you can use `DATETIMEFROMPARTS`

```
DECLARE @year INT = 2018
DECLARE @month INT = 5

SELECT DATETIMEFROMPARTS(@year, @month, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```